# Some assignments fail silently in javascript strict mode (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Strict mode definition in MDN says below

> Any assignment that silently fails in normal code (assignment to a
>   non-writable property, assignment to a getter-only property,
>   assignment to a new property on a non-extensible object) will throw in
>   strict mode

So an assignment to document which silently fails in normal code throws an exception in strict mode (as expected).

```
> var document = 1

// normal mode
> document
  #document

// strict mode
x Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'document' of object [object Object]
```

But in case of `window`, there is no error in strict mode. It just silently fails.

```
> var window = 1
> window
  Window {external: Object, chrome: Object, document: document…}
```

Another case is `console` can be reassigned without any error and retains the assignment.

```
> var console = 1
> console
  1
```

But `localStorage` neither retain the assignment nor throw an exception.

```
> var localStorage = 1
> localStorage
  Storage {}
```

Why do window & localStorage silently fail even on strict mode? Which others behave like this?

(Chrome 48.0.2564.116)